# Response after setting a event remainder in exchange

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, outlook-restapi

I am creating a normal event. In the created event I have set the remainder time to None...But while getting the response JSON I get RemainderMinutesBeforeStart = 15.

In the UI it shows remainder as None and in response I get the time.... Is this a bug or a default value?

Also I am setting up email remainder but there is no tag that describes about the email remainder details in the JSon response...

Can someone help me with these questions?

Answer (score 0):

this is the default value for the reminder and even if it is set to None in the UI you will get a value in RemainderMinutesBeforeStart.There is another property for the events - IsReminderOn that you can check.